# #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going to create the movie downloading website. Now I insert my records but  I faced on mysql issue

Details are given

> Databse Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movie_info`
(
    `ID` int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    `movie_name`        varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_thumb`       varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_lang`        varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_time`        varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_rating`      varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_charactors`  varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_director`    varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_theme`       varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_size`        varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_quality`     varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_views`       varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_genre`       varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `movie_year`        varchar (200) NOT NULL,
    `DateTime`          DATETIME  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID);
);
```

> SQL query:

```
INSERT
INTO
    `movie_info` (`movie_name`, `movie_thumb`)
VALUES(
    ("asdf" , "4q2NNj4S5dG2RLF9CpXsej7yXl-200x300.jpg" ),
    ("asdf" , "7IRy0iHdaS0JI3ng4ZYlk5gLSFn-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "bB42KDdfWkOvmzmYkmK58ZlCa9P-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "db32LaOibwEliAmSL2jjDF6oDdj-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "1cSHEKYYP8Dpi4o1iBVd4U75FYt-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "dPrUPFcgLfNbmDL8V69vcrTyEfb-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "eBzf9d09Vgq2HSVC4fIZm1QNQd-200x300.jpg" ),
    ("asdf" , "rVR3uN1yPRqYBBtNFSrEKCpRhaK-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "ud7XxBDuoq2aTi8HajDXP6F0bSU-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "vqzNJRH4YyquRiWxCCOH0aXggHI-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "w9kR8qbmQ01HwnvK4alvnQ2ca0L-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "yhoL2CxBp9IwMhHrCj6FIb2lrYR-200x300.jpg")
)
```

> MySQL said:

```
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Any one help this issue ??

Comment: You have an extra opening paren after `VALUES`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you explain this solution

Comment: The syntax should be INSERT INTO table(c1,c2,...)
VALUES 
   (v11,v12,...),
   (v21,v22,...),
    ...
   (vnn,vn2,...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will run without error

```
INSERT
INTO
    `movie_info` (`movie_name`, `movie_thumb`)
VALUES
    ("asdf" , "4q2NNj4S5dG2RLF9CpXsej7yXl-200x300.jpg" ),
    ("asdf" , "7IRy0iHdaS0JI3ng4ZYlk5gLSFn-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "bB42KDdfWkOvmzmYkmK58ZlCa9P-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "db32LaOibwEliAmSL2jjDF6oDdj-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "1cSHEKYYP8Dpi4o1iBVd4U75FYt-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "dPrUPFcgLfNbmDL8V69vcrTyEfb-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "eBzf9d09Vgq2HSVC4fIZm1QNQd-200x300.jpg" ),
    ("asdf" , "rVR3uN1yPRqYBBtNFSrEKCpRhaK-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "ud7XxBDuoq2aTi8HajDXP6F0bSU-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "vqzNJRH4YyquRiWxCCOH0aXggHI-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "w9kR8qbmQ01HwnvK4alvnQ2ca0L-200x300.jpg"),
    ("asdf" , "yhoL2CxBp9IwMhHrCj6FIb2lrYR-200x300.jpg");
```